# Installed Java 7u9 and Eclipse (Juno) but Eclipse doesn't see JavaFX2

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx-2

Everywhere that I read, as of Java 7u7, JavaFX2 is bundled with the JRE and JDK. So I am confused as to why when I run Eclipse, it tells me "**The import javafx cannot be resolved**".

I have no other JDKs or JREs installed but 7u9, so why would I not be able to see JavaFX2 from Eclipse?

Many thanks :)

Comment: make you sure u have jfxrt.jar file in your project build path ?

Comment: have you checked your eclipse default and project jdk setting is using the new java 7?

Comment: That did the trick, invariant!

I assumed since it was integrated into Java 7 it would see it automatically, after all this is where the JAR is stored "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\jre\lib"

Oh well, thanks :D

Comment: Which version of Eclipse?  Is it one that says it supports Java 7?

Comment: Hi nitind, when we worked on it we all used the latest stable Eclipse for Java. So long ago I can't remember what exact version it was, but the user invariant's answer seemingly explained it as simply being down to current version of JDK not including the library in the default path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, for jdk7u9, Eclipse does not add the `jfxrt.jar` file from your `jre\lib` directory to the project build path libraries when we create a new Java project. You have to do it manually or you can install the [e(fx)clipse](http://efxclipse.org/) plugin to Eclipse, which will make your JavaFX development easier :)

Eclipse is following the default settings for the JRE 7u9 default boot classpath (which is to not include `jfxrt.jar`).  A future JRE version will place `jfxrt.jar` on the boot classpath so you won't need to manually add the `jfxrt.jar` file to project build path libraries.  You can track this [JRE feature](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7166330).

Comment: @jewelsea your edit clarifies root cause of the issue, thanks :)

Comment: after e(fx)clipse  installed,are you creating new javaFX project or java Project ?

Comment: I have a "Java Project". How do I convert it to JavaFX? I tried right clicking on the project in the package explorer but I don't see any javafx stuff in the context menu.

Comment: if you have an existing project add jfxrt.jar to your java build bath.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `jfxrt.jar` to the project build path will enable eclipse to find it and permit you to develop and execute your code from within eclipse. However, when you deploy your software, it will no longer be able to find `jfxrt.jar` unless you also place it on the classpath. This gets messy as you have to muck around finding the location of the `jdk`/`jre` and searching inside for the location of `jfxrt.jar`.

From what I understand, the long term plan is to move `jfxrt.jar` from the `lib` folder in the `jre` to the `lib/ext` folder. This will place it somewhere where it is found by default without needing to add stuff to your classpath. Unfortunately this is not likely to happen before Java 8 is released!

Meanwhile, the easiest solution appears to be to use the bundled [`javafxpackager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafxpackager001.htm) tool to create your jar file, rather than the `jar` tool. There is also an `ant` based solution, but I'm not familiar with it. The packager will create your jar file, and insert a launcher class that finds jfxrt.jar and dynamically adds it to your app's classpath at runtime. It also complains if the `jre` or installed `javafx` is too old and prompts the user to download a newer version. Then it calls your application via a class you specified on the command line.
 (usually the class with your `main()` method).

It works for both native javafx applications and plain old Swing applications. If you had extra stuff in the manifest of your jar file, such as another ClassPath entry, you can specify that on the command line as well, for inclusion in the new jar file.

Comment: Wonderful! We'd long since solved the initial problem, but there was still the problem of how to package it effectively. You sir, are a good man, and have just most likely bumped my teams grade up a good few bands! :) Cheers!